# How to pass to an EXPECT_CALL a reference of an object from within a unit test that's instantiated elsewhere?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to mock a virtual function `Foo` from an abstract class with `EXPECT_CALL` in unit test however the trick is the mock method takes in a const reference of the struct `SomeStruct` and the struct itself is created within a function.

In the following snippet, `SomeStruct s` is instantiated within `Source::Bar()` and there's no way for me to have the same reference of `s` in the unit test that I could pass to the `EXPECT_CALL`.

Hence, I am getting the following warning

> GMOCK WARNING:
> Uninteresting mock function call - returning directly.
> Function call: Foo
> NOTE: You can safely ignore the above warning unless this call should not happen.  Do not suppress it by blindly adding an EXPECT_CALL() if you don't mean to enforce the call.

Is there a way to mock `Handler::Foo` given from the unit test given it takes a reference of a struct in the parameter that's not created within a unit test itself?

```
  struct SomeStruct 
  {
    int a;
  };

  class Handler
  {
    public:
    virtual void Foo(const SomeStruct&) = 0;
  };

  class Source
  {
    std::weak_ptr<Handler> _handler;

    public:
    Source(std::weak_ptr<Handler> handler) : _handler(handler) {}

    void Bar()
    { 
      SomeStruct s = {.a = 10};           // simulate this s struct
      if (auto sp = _handler.lock())
      {
         sp->Foo(s);   // simulate this call
      }
    }
  };

  class MockHandler : public Handler
  {
     public:
     MOCK_METHOD(void, Foo, (const SomeStruct&), (override));
  };
  
  TEST_F(UtClass, TestSourceBar)
  {
    auto sp = std::make_shared<MockHandler>();
    SomeStruct s = {.a = 10};
 
    // can't pass "s" to EXPECT_CALL because that won't match with `s` being created inside Source::Bar

    //EXPECT_CALL(*sp, Foo(s)).WillRepeatedly(Return()); 
   
    Source source (sp);
    source.Bar();
  }
```

Comment: Hi to whoever closed my question: are you certain the post you linked it with has my answer? cause I don't think so

Comment: I think the answer in the duplicate solves your problem. If I understood correctly, you want to expect call to `Foo` with an argument that is `SomeStruct` with it's field `a == 10` (this is what your `Source::Bar` does)? `CustomObjMatcher` in the answer does that exactly. Or if not, please explain what else is the problem.